# A host your own, open source dashboard

Tags: open-source, self-hosted, dashboard

Can anyone recommend a web-based, host your own, open source dashboard - something like [Netvibes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Netvibes)?

I want something clean/well designed, password protected, doesn't have to have lots of plugins available.

All I'll be using it for is adding links and perhaps a todo list.  Needs to save data to flatfiles or SQL - no local saving.  Made with PHP would be great.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details. A Dashboard for what shall it be? What data shall be displayed, and where shall it be taken from? What must it interface with?

Comment: What is wrong with Netvibes that you are not considering it?

Comment: @Izzy, well I did list some tech requirements - self hosted, open source, php and personal requirements - well designed, adding links, todo list.  Beyond that I'm open to suggestions.  After some research I'm trying out Subrion at the moment.  It seems to have everything I want and works well but is really overkill for what I need - simpler would be good.

Comment: @Richard Chambers, I've been using Netvibes for about five years.  Tired of the redirects to upgrade, the modules that break and being able to do little about it, want to take a bit more control etc.

Comment: Yes, you've listed some *tech* requirements – but the *functional* ones are missing: what details shall the Dashboard display? By defininition, a [Dashboard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dashboard_(disambiguation)) is a control panel – but it's ambiguous for what unless you specify that (which you missed).

Comment: Thank you for providing a _definition_ for a control panel for me — the five years of using Netvibes hadn't made that clear to me.  The use of the dashboard was implied in my original question however I shall explicitly state it in case it wasn't clear.  I need a dashboard to hold links to various websites.  A module that can be added through the dashboard interface, similar to Netvibes, is preferable for this.  Subrion does it through a back-end.  I would also like some other simple modules that can be added to the dashboard such as a to do list.  That's all I need.

Answer (score 1):

One option is POSH (used to be called Portaneo). It is not maintained very actively but it is kind of an open source version of Netvibes, or at least what Netvibes used to be.
One thing I'm not sure, is if it has password protection, but you can always set-up a login page or something with Apache/Nginx.

You can find it here, along with a clear list of features : https://sourceforge.net/projects/posh/

It was last updated two years ago, but again last I checked it was working well for what it's supposed to do (RSS, basic widgets, etc.).

**EDIT :**

Since the documentation is a little lacking, here's how to install it :

1. You need a LAMP stack
2. Copy the folder (from sourceforge, extracted) to your `www` dir
3. Give ownership of the new sub dir to *www-data*
4. Navigate to `http://host/posh_dir/install/`
5. In the install page indicate the db host, db user and password, and the name of the database (the db will be created). Also indicate the admin user and password for POSH.
6. Done !

Since the project is not highly maintained, I suggest anyway to only use it if you're ready to get your hands dirty. In my case, I really wanted something like netvibes (as I was used to it) so it was worth it.

If you want something faster to setup and not necessarily a netvibes clone, the best option available seems in my opinion to be [**Smashing**](https://smashing.github.io/).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  Looks interesting but can't find any details about how to install.  Since it's quite big/uses mysql etc. I'm not spending the time trawling through all the files to figure it out.

Comment: I edited my answer to add more info :)